# Save network configuration

Tags: windows, networking

I use my laptop on 2 different networks. Each time I change the network I have to change the IP address, subnet mask, gateway etc.

I'm looking for an application or something that can remember my configurations and I would like to do only a click of a button to change it...

Comment: Can you please update the question with details like OS used, both network with DHCP or static IP addressing scheme or mixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the "Alternate Configuration" features in Windows to use a set of static settings when it fails to get them via DHCP

1. Start>Control Panel>Network
   Connections
2. Right-click the network
   adapter>Properties.
3. Select Internet Protocol
   (TCP/IP)>Properties.
4. General tab> Set to DHCP.
5. Alternate Configuration tab>"User
   configured,">fill in the static IP
   address details
6. Click OK in all Windows

Comment: it is nice for two places only...