# Free IP Changer

Tags: networking

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [A good solution to switch between different network settings?](https://superuser.com/questions/47429/a-good-solution-to-switch-between-different-network-settings)

I use a laptop (windows 7 64 bit) with wired and wireless networking. To access internet, i need to continuously change my IP and DNS server configuration.

Can you please suggest a free utility where i can store the different configurations and apply them with a click of a button?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What operating system, what network manager?

Comment: possible duplicates: http://superuser.com/questions/47429 http://superuser.com/questions/64312 http://superuser.com/questions/36470 http://superuser.com/questions/26368

Comment: Thanks a lot for all the answers. NetSetMan worked like a charm for me on Windows 7 ultimate, 64 bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two programs to switch between pre-configured network settings:

**[IP Organizer 2](http://www.bilgisayar-dunyasi.com/yazilim/iporganizer.html)**

[image]

the website is in Turkish, here's the [download link](http://www.bilgisayar-dunyasi.com/yazilim/dosyalar/IP_Organizer2.exe).

*IP Organizer is freeware.*

**[NetSetMan](http://www.netsetman.com/index.php?s=nsm)**

[image]

*NetSetMan is free for personal use.*

Comment: Does it work on Windows 7 64 bit?

Answer (score 3):

See the open source [Net Profiles](http://code.google.com/p/netprofiles/) :

> With Net Profiles, mobile computing
>   becomes a whole lot easier. It
>   eliminates the need to manually
>   reconfigure your network settings when
>   you move your desktop/laptop computer
>   to another location. Once a profile is
>   created, Net Profiles can configure
>   your IP settings, proxy settings,
>   mapped drives, default printer,
>   wallpaper, and screen resolution with
>   a click of a button; as well as run
>   any number of user-defined
>   applications upon activation of a
>   profile.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is also Netswitcher, a utility that I used some time ago, especially when network connectivity was not at all reliable on my home network. It saved me hours of reconfigurations. See at http://www.netswitcher.com/